# Как удалить класс у всех элементов класса и добавить элементу, на который нажали?

Tags: javascript

Пока что получается либо одно, либо другое, а нужно чтобы эти два действия совершались вместе. Добавить нужный класс элементу, на который нажали, получается, но если перед этим вставить строку, в которой удаляется класс у всех остальных элементов следующая строка, которая добавляет класс, уже не работает почему-то. В чем ошибка?

```js
var menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');

for (var i = 0; i <= menuItem.length; i++) {
    menuItem[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        for (var j = 0; j <= menuItem.length; j++) {
            menuItem[j].classList.remove("active");
        };
        this.classList.add("active");
    });
};
```

Comment: а почему в условиях выхода из цикла `<=` ?

Comment: Я постоянно путаю, в каких случаях надо использовать `<=`, а в каких `<`. По-видимому, в этом и была ошибка. Спасибо, что обратили внимание!

Comment: так да, вы вышли за границу массива, упало исключение и код далее не выполнился

Comment: используйте [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) и не будет путаницы с индексами)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych лучше уж `for (const el of arr){}`, если конечно не идти функциональным стилем.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше используйте делегирование событий, вместо того чтобы вешать обработчик на каждый элемент.

Допустим есть родительский элемент .container
И в нем лежат ваши .menu__item

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.container');
let menuItem = parent.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');


parent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // Отлавливаем элемент в родители на который мы нажали
  let target = event.target;
  
  // Проверяем тот ли это элемент который нам нужен
  if(target.classList.contains('menu__item')) {
    for(let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
      // Убираем у других
      menuItem[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    // Добавляем тому на который нажали
    target.classList.add('active');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.menu__item {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="menu__item"></div>
<div class="menu__item"></div>
<div class="menu__item"></div>
<div class="menu__item"></div>
<div class="menu__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: в чем смысл делегирования если в вашем коде список меню итемов статичен ?
Да и добавлять класс таргету на каждой итерации удаления у остальных, также не имеет смысла

Comment: не заметил, ошибочка вышла

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Поясните, для этой задачи лучше вложенный цикл, и свой слушатель на каждый элемент?

Comment: мб я не прав, но как по мне, так делегация имеет смысл только в случаи динамически изменяемого DOM. Да и нету там вложеног цикла, просто один раз повесили хендлеры на нужные елементы и забыли, а вот в случаи с делегацией будем каждый раз проверять класс-лист елемента, куда кликнули(даже если клик был мимо) и далее делать все тот же цикл

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Я не обвиняю) Просто самому интересно стало) Спасибо)